# Rails 4.2.1 - update html with <render ...> doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I'm trying to update comments after submitting a new one via AJAX. Comments are rendered with a partial. Comments are definitely submitted correctly, since they show up when I refresh the page. After lots of trial and error I could limit the erroneous code to the render action within the html that I'm trying to update.

Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @Comment = Comment.new(comments_params)
    @Comment.save
    respond_to(:js)
end

private

    def comments_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:post_id, :author, :body, :value, :parent_id)
    end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$('.allcommentsof<%= @Comment.post_id %>').html(<%= render :partial => "comment", :locals => {:id => post.id} %>);
```

div I'm trying to update

```
<div class="allcommentsof<%= post.id %>">
    <%= render :partial => 'comment', :locals => {:id => post.id} %>
</div>
```

partial _comment.html.erb in the same folder as create.js.erb

```
<% @Comments = Comment.where(:post_id => id, :parent_id => nil).order("value DESC") %><br>
<% @Comments.each do |c| %>
<div><%= c.author %>: <%= c.body %> <span class="badge">$<%= c.value %></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: 10px"></span></div>
<div class="subcomms"> 
    <% @Subcomms = Comment.where(:parent_id => c.id) %>
    <% @Subcomms.each do |s| %>
        <%= s.author %>: <%= s.body %> <span class="badge">$<%= s.value %></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: 10px"></span>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for Comment.new, url: comments_create_path do |d| %>
        <%= d.text_field :body, :autocomplete => false %>
        <%= d.hidden_field :author, :value => current_user.username %>
        <%= d.hidden_field :post_id, :value => id %>
        <%= d.hidden_field :value, :value => 0 %>
        <%= d.hidden_field :parent_id, :value => c.id %>
        <%= d.submit "Submit", style: "opacity: 0" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I'd welcome any idea you have for making this work

log

```
Started POST "/comments/create" for 79.225.166.124 at 2015-08-06 20:22:32 +0000
Cannot render console from 79.225.166.124! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"body"=>"test", "author"=>"Lenco", "post_id"=>"99", "value"=>"0", "parent_id"=>""}}
User Load (27.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(8.4ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #any_of directly is deprecated and will be removed in activerecord_any_of-1.2.
Please call it with #where : User.where.any_of(cond1, cond2). (called from get_offer at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:12)
(45.8ms)  SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM "offers" WHERE (("offers"."buyer_id" = 1 OR "offers"."post_id" IN (21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 57, 60, 64, 80, 81)))  ORDER BY amount DESC
(14.8ms)  SELECT SUM("users"."wealth") FROM "users"
(6.2ms)  SELECT SUM("posts"."value") FROM "posts"
(1.7ms)  SELECT "users"."id", "users"."wealth" FROM "users"
(3.3ms)  SELECT SUM("posts"."value") FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1]]
(0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("posts"."value") FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 3]]
(1.0ms)  SELECT SUM("posts"."value") FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 10]]
(0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("posts"."value") FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 11]]
User Load (5.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
(2.4ms)  begin transaction
SQL (9.3ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("post_id", "author", "body", "value", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["post_id", 99], ["author", "Lenco"], ["body", "test"], ["value", 0], ["created_at", "2015-08-06 20:22:33.143458"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-06 20:22:33.143458"]]
(44.2ms)  commit transaction
Comment Load (7.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ? AND "comments"."parent_id" IS NULL  ORDER BY value DESC  [["post_id", 99]]
Comment Load (7.6ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 90]]
Comment Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 94]]
Comment Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 95]]
Comment Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 96]]
Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 97]]
 Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (228.2ms)
 Rendered comments/create.js.erb (359.3ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 1145ms (Views: 409.2ms | ActiveRecord: 191.5ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've escaped and cleaned up your create.js.erb file. You are missing the @Comment object in your locals.

```
$('.allcommentsof<%= @Comment.post.id %>').html("<%= j render('comment', id: @Comment.post.id) %>");
```

If this doesn't fix your problem could you please provide your log file.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be liked that, yes, but unfortunately it didn't make my code work. I added the log file for you.

Comment: I got it to work by wrapping the render code in double quotation mark and using for everything inside, including the partial, only single quotation marks. Your answer did help me too, so I'll mark it correct. Thank you.